# Create array formula to collate data from matching IDs in a single cell - array not expanding

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

**I'm using Google sheets to collect feedback.**

Each session has a unique ID ( **column A**). I want to amalgamate feedback (**Column B**) that comes from the same session into a single cell in **column C**

It works with the formulas shown but each time someone submits feedback using google forms it creates a new row in the sheet and I have to manually copy and paste the formula into the newly created row. I solved this problem with other data i have been collecting by using an array formula.

**However I can't figure out how to get this working as an array formula.** Help!

```
    A      B           C           Formulas in column C
1
2   as1     ok      ok              =IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1 & "," & B2)
3   as1     short   ok, short       =IF(A3<>A2,B3,C2 & "," & B3)
4   as1     fun     ok, short, fun  =IF(A4<>A3,B4,C3 & "," & B4)
5   bg2     hard    hard            =IF(A5<>A4,B5,C4 & "," & B5)
6   bg2     easy    hard, easy      =IF(A6<>A5,B6,C5 & "," & B6)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A50<>A2:A49,B3:B50,C2:C49& "," & B3:B50))
```

Comment: I couldn't get this array to build up the feedback - see column C  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vReMrqymodxesLsD-NbEbpCgobSMhPWTjXqo1mm_sC5d1eBvCJ6vPE1KexRSt6SqKXF0SMr_LNWX4Lb/pubhtml?gid=1029827199&single=true